# Is it possible to play a video as audio with jPlayer

Tags: audio, video, jplayer

When I play a video using jPlayer in iOS Safari, the video goes fullscreen.

Is there anyway to play only the audio part of the video so that the video won't show up?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes of curse that is possible, in the jplayer.org under its logo they wrote:

> HTML5 Audio & Video for jQuery

and you can just play audio with that.

[DEMO](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-01-supplied-mp3/)

Comment: You're right that jPlayer supports video playback, but I don't think this is what OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to disable video by using CSS, include the following code before the closing `</head>` tag.

```
<style type="text/css">
.jp-jplayer video { display: none !important; }
</style>
```